# Escape a line inside a format function

Tags: python-3.x, format, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use \n inside a format function in python, since it's not possible to do it using fstrings. But I'm not sure how it's done.

```
raw_data = {'post 1': 'link 1', 'post 2': 'link 2'}

data = [("Post:{}\nLink: {}").format(title, link) for title, link in raw_data.items()]

print(data)
```

Which prints: `['Post:post 1\nLink: link 1\n', 'Post:post 2\nLink: link 2\n']`

Expected result:

Post: post 1

Link: link 1

Post: post 2

Link: link 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this:

```
>>> raw_data = {'post 1': 'link 1', 'post 2': 'link 2'}
>>> data = [("Post:{}\nLink: {}").format(title, link) for title, link in raw_data.items()]
>>> print(data)
['Post:post 1\nLink: link 1', 'Post:post 2\nLink: link 2']
```

That's not what you expected, but that's the Python normal output. See [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream

Let's try:

```
>>> str(data)
"['Post:post 1\\nLink: link 1', 'Post:post 2\\nLink: link 2']"
```

Note the double quotes around the result and the double backslash: `str(data)` is a string representing the list and `print` prints that string... not its content. It's very different from:

```
>>> for s in data: print(s)
...
Post:post 1
Link: link 1
Post:post 2
Link: link 2
```

To focus on the difference, take a look at a single string:

```
>>> s = "a\nb"
>>> s # the value of the string s
'a\nb'
>>> print(s) # outputs the string s
a
b
```

To summarize: printing the elements of the list is different from printing the list itself. Use `for s in data: print(s)` to get what you want.

**EDIT** if you want to return a printable result from a function, you have to build your own string, that is `data[0]+"\n"+data[1]`, or with a `join`:

```
>>> s = "\n".join(data) 
>>> s # return this string
'Post:post 1\nLink: link 1\nPost:post 2\nLink: link 2'
>>> print(s)
Post:post 1
Link: link 1
Post:post 2
Link: link 2
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to use return with these results, so a for loop won't do. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `return` a formatted list I had to convert said list into a string.
So I did:

```
raw_data = {'post 1': 'link 1', 'post 2': 'link 2'}

data = [("Post:{}\nLink: {}").format(title, link) for title, link in raw_data.items()]
return ''.join(data)
```

Comment: I did not see you had found a solution. Beware: if you join with an empty string, the second line will be:`Link:link 1Post:post 2`... See my answer: use `"\n".join`

Comment: Oh, yes. I actually used `data = [("Post:{}\nLink: {}\n").format(title, link)`
That's why I didn't see a bad formatted print. Thanks for pointing that out!